# How can I resize PDF page using bookmark for specific page?

Tags: java, apache, pdfbox

How can I resize the page of a specific PDF page? Do I have to use the book mark to pick the specific page which I want to resize? If yes how can I do that?

Below is the code I was trying to resize and have used apache pdf box.

```
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDRectangle;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.InvalidPasswordException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.documentnavigation.outline.PDDocumentOutline;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.documentnavigation.outline.PDOutlineItem;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.documentnavigation.outline.PDOutlineNode;

public class PDFLoader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidPasswordException, IOException, PrinterException {


         //Loading an existing document 
          File file = new File("d:\\pdf\\source.pdf"); 
          PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file); 
          PDPage page1 = document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().get(0);
          PDPage page2 = document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().get(1);




          //PDRectangle mediaBox = page1.getMediaBox();

          //if (mediaBox.getWidth() == 6 * 72 && mediaBox.getHeight() == 8 * 72)

          PDDocumentOutline outline =  document.getDocumentCatalog().getDocumentOutline();

          PDRectangle mediaBox = new PDRectangle(8.0f * 72, 13.5f * 72);
          PDRectangle mediaBox1 = new PDRectangle(8.5f * 72, 11.5f * 72);

          page1.setMediaBox(mediaBox1);
          if(getBookmark(outline, "")){
          page2.setMediaBox(mediaBox);
          }

          PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
          doc.addPage(page1);
          doc.addPage(page2);

          doc.save("d:\\pdf\\newDocument.pdf");
          doc.close();

    }

    public static boolean getBookmark(PDOutlineNode bookmark, String indentation) throws IOException
    {
        PDOutlineItem current = bookmark.getFirstChild();
        while (current != null)

        {
            System.out.println(indentation + current.getTitle());

            if(current.getTitle().equals("2016 Users Kit Final 9")){

                System.out.println("Returning as true as the book mark is found");
                return true;
            }

            getBookmark(current, indentation + "    ");
            current = current.getNextSibling();

            }

        System.out.println("Returning as false as the book mark is not found");

        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: First choose a product, then clarify what you want. To you want to resize the page or do you want to zoom the display of a page when somebody clicks on a bookmark?

Comment: I have rephrased my question and posted my code above.

Comment: Your question is not about iText. I am going to edit that tag away.

Comment: you only manipulate the media box but completely ignore the crop box.

Comment: Either I still don't understand, or it is too easy: the bookmark is irrelevant. Btw you can get a page through `document.getPage(i)`.

Comment: There are 3 pages in my pdf file and am only trying to resize for page 2 but not the other pages.

Comment: Then don't do it.

Comment: I have to do it as it is the requirement and I did it.

Comment: Sorry either this makes no sense or I don't understand what you mean. If you only want to resize page 2 then make the call only for page 2. (0-based, so call `document.getPage(1)` to get your PDPage object).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. This pdf related programming using pdf box is pretty new to me and that is why I could be ambiguous with my questions. I initially start using itext but found pdf box which seems to be easy and  I switch to it. Right now the pdf file which I am working on is of three pages but in the future I may get the pdf with more than 100 pages, in that sense how can I pick the 50th or 70th page only for resizing to set it  7.3 x 11 page size using bookmark or any other option to link it? I have to resize it because those pages have ID cards which need to of 7 x 11 for print. :)

Comment: Well you just retrieve the needed page by calling `document.getPage(69)` or whatever. If you get the page because the bookmark is named "ID card" then you retrieve the page through the bookmark... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44982486/how-to-select-pdf-page-using-bookmark-in-pdf-box but read the comments too.

Comment: Ok I will give it a try. Thank you.

Comment: Glad that it worked. Please either delete the question or answer it yourself, to avoid "orphans".

Comment: I actually referred to this post for loading up the bookmarks and it worked. Thanks again for your help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44982486/how-to-select-pdf-page-using-bookmark-in-pdf-box